# Efficient code for draw a sierpinski triangle with matlab

Tags: matlab, recursion, fractals

Following is my code:

```
function sierpinski(A, B, C, n)
    if n == 0
        patch([A(1), B(1), C(1)], [A(2), B(2), C(2)], [0.0 0.0 0.0]);
    else
       sierpinski(A, (A + B)/2, (A + C)/2, n-1);
       sierpinski(B, (B + A)/2, (B + C)/2, n-1);
       sierpinski(C, (C + A)/2, (C + B)/2, n-1);
end

% sierpinski([0 0], [1 0], [.5 .8], 8)
```

It's not very effectly. I want to first generating all data then patched, but I don't know how to correctly used. Also, can my code be written use for loops?

Comment: Do some research, a search engine should turn up `O(10)` solutions for you.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I don't think that's fair - the OP has already figured out how to plot the sierpinski triangle (their code works, but is slow because of the ~6000 calls to `patch`) and they are asking how they can generate all the data separately and then plot it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your idea to write one function to generate the data and another to plot it is a good one - it's often a good idea to separate data generation from processing, and processing from output. I would do it something like this:

```
function out = sierpinski(a, b, c, n)

    if n == 0
        out.xvals = [a(1), b(1), c(1)];
        out.yvals = [a(2), b(2), c(2)];
    else
        out1 = sierpinski(a, (a+b)/2, (a+c)/2, n-1);
        out2 = sierpinski(b, (a+b)/2, (b+c)/2, n-1);
        out3 = sierpinski(c, (a+c)/2, (b+c)/2, n-1);
        out = [out1, out2, out3];
    end

end
```

This creates a struct of length `3^n`, each entry of which contains the coordinates of one of the small triangles in the sierpinski triangle. Your code to plot it might then look like

```
>> out = sierpinski([0,0], [1,0], [0.5, sqrt(3)/2], 8);
>> figure(); hold on;
>> for i = 1:length(out)
       patch(out(i).xvals, out(i).yvals, 'k');
   end
```

That crashes on my machine (it seems that Matlab doesn't handle thousands of patches on the same plot very well) but a similar loop which plots one point at the corner of each small triangle.

```
>> x = [out.xvals];
>> y = [out.yvals];
>> plot(x, y, '.');
```

which produces this plot

[image]

Comment: Can i get some help ? i want to make the same triangle, but m not getting the code. even how to add it in file. can i get code in email or here. some thing like that ?

Comment: The code is already in my answer. If you explain what it is you don't understand then maybe I can help, but just saying "I'm not getting the code" won't get you very far.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any code-examples ready, but:

Instead of drawing each triangle as a single patch-object, you could try drawing all triangles in one large patch.
Basically you'd only need to concatenate the x- and y-coordinates for each triangle separated by a NaN - this will prevent the patch from drawing lines connecting individual triangles.
E.g. the following line produces two separate triangles:

`p = patch( [0 0.5 1 0 NaN 2 2.5 3 2 NaN ], [ 0 1 0 0 NaN 2 3 2 2 NaN], 'k')`

Mind that, to have a closed triangle you need 4 points per triangle this way, the last point being identical to the first.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
For each recursion level, you can 'erase' the central triangles, so you have to patch many fewer triangles. For example, at first level, you have three 'up' triangles and only one 'down' triangle. You can path this, instead of the other three.
a more compact routine is:

```
function sierpinski(rec)
  [x, x0] = deal(cat(3, [1 0]', [-1 0]', [0 sqrt(3)]')); 
  for k = 1 : rec x = x(:,:) + x0 * 2 ^ k / 2; 
end 
patch('Faces', reshape(1 : 3 * 3 ^ k, 3, '')', 'Vertices', x(:,:)') 
end
```

---

So you have to fill much less triangles if...

```
function sierpinski(rec)
close all
%Main Triangle
hFig=figure;
units=get(hFig,'units');
set(hFig,'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1], 'Color', 'white');
set(hFig,'units',units); clear units
hold on
Vx=[0 0.5 1]; Vy=[0 realsqrt(3)/2 0];
fill(Vx,Vy,'b')
%the number of white triangles = sum(3.^(0:1:rec-1))
whitex=NaN(3,sum(3.^(0:1:rec-1))); whitey=whitex; K=1;
for S=1:rec
    [Vx,Vy]=sierpinskisect;
end
fill(whitex,whitey,'w')

function [outX,outY]=sierpinskisect
    %the number of blue triangles = 3^S
    L=size(Vx,1);
    outX=NaN(3*L,3); outY=outX; J=1;
    for I=1:L
        %left blue triangle
        outX(J,:)=[Vx(I,1) mean(Vx(I,(1:2))) mean(Vx(I,([1 3])))];
        outY(J,:)=[Vy(I,1) mean(Vy(I,(1:2))) mean(Vy(I,([1 3])))];
        J=J+1;
        %right blue triangle
        outX(J,:)=[mean(Vx(I,([1 3]))) mean(Vx(I,(2:3))) Vx(I,3)];
        outY(J,:)=[mean(Vy(I,([1 3]))) mean(Vy(I,(2:3))) Vy(I,3)];
        J=J+1;
        %upper blue triangle
        outX(J,:)=[mean(Vx(I,(1:2))) Vx(I,2) mean(Vx(I,(2:3)))];
        outY(J,:)=[mean(Vy(I,(1:2))) Vy(I,2) mean(Vy(I,(2:3)))];
        J=J+1;
        %white triangle
        whitex(:,K)=[outX(J-3,2);outX(J-3,3);outX(J-2,2)];
        whitey(:,K)=[outY(J-3,2);outY(J-3,3);outY(J-2,2)];
        K=K+1;
    end
end
```

end

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Answers should explain in words how they  answer the question in addition to showing the code.

Comment: ok, sorry, It was my first comment.
for each recursion level, you can 'erase' the central triangles, so you have to patch much more less triangles.
For example, at first level, you have three 'up' triangles and only one 'down' triangle. You can path this, instead of the other three

Comment: a more compact routine is:
function sierpinski(rec)
[x, x0] = deal(cat(3, [1 0]', [-1 0]', [0 sqrt(3)]'));
for k = 1 : rec
    x = x(:,:) + x0 * 2 ^ k / 2;
end
patch('Faces', reshape(1 : 3 * 3 ^ k, 3, '')', 'Vertices', x(:,:)')
end

Comment: I tried to edit your comments in, please let me know if the code is wrong  I may have not done the right line endings etc.